# .Net compact framework: inherit from DataGridTextBoxColumn, GetColumnValueAtRow is missing

Tags: .net, datagrid, compact-framework, overloading

The `DataGrid` in the .net compact framework (I'm using v3.5) is a bit limited. I try to display a `bool`-value with app-defined texts like "on/off" or translations of "true/false". I've created a class `DataGridBoolColumn` which inherits from `DataGridTextBoxColumn` and there I override the `Paint`-method. But I've problems with retrieving the current value of the cell, since there's no `GetColumnValueAtRow`-method in the comapct framework.

In my small app I know, that the grid is bound to a `DataView` and I can pass the relevant objects to my constructor so I can look up the value. But this is not a real generic way so I can't use this class in other apps with other bound data sources. Is there a "righter" way to get the current value in the `Paint` method?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps someone

```
DirectCast(DirectCast(source.List(rowNum), System.Object), System.Data.DataRowView).Row(Me.MappingName, Data.DataRowVersion.Current)
```